# If a function does not converge point-wise, then it doesn't converge uniformly as well, right?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Here is the function: $f_n(x) = \sqrt{\sin^2 x + n^{-4}}, \ \ x \in R$. If $x \neq \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k \text{ or } x \neq 2\pi k, \ \ k \in Z$ then the function doesn't converge at all even point wise, am I right? So, how do I show formally that it doesn't converge?

Comment: No. It converges pointwise to $|\sin x|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x)=|\sin x|$. Hence $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|{=\left|\sqrt {\sin^2 x+n^{-4}}-|\sin x|\right|
\\=\left|{(\sqrt {\sin^2 x+n^{-4}})^2-|\sin x|^2\over \sqrt {\sin^2 x+n^{-4}}+|\sin x|}\right|
\\=\left|{{\sin^2 x+n^{-4}}-\sin^2 x\over \sqrt {\sin^2 x+n^{-4}}+|\sin x|}\right|
\\=\left|{n^{-4}\over \sqrt {\sin^2 x+n^{-4}}+|\sin x|}\right|
\\={n^{-4}\over \sqrt {\sin^2 x+n^{-4}}+|\sin x|}
\\\le {n^{-4}\over \sqrt {\sin^2 x+n^{-4}}}
\\\le {n^{-4}\over \sqrt {n^{-4}}}
\\= {n^{-4}\over {n^{-2}}}
\\={1\over n^2}
\\<\epsilon
}$$
hence by choosing $n>\sqrt{1\over \epsilon}$, we can have $f_n(x)$ arbitrarily close to $f(x)$ at any point, hence **$f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ uniformly**.